# Connect from a computer to a Raspberry connected in a second computer (RNDIS)

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, raspberry-pi, routing-table

I have a Raspberry Pi attached to my laptop using the USB (RNDIS) so I can see the Raspberry Pi as a Network Card + Device. I can SSH from my laptop to the Raspberry Pi using the 192.168.64.1 IP. I would like to SSH from my workstation which is on another network (192.168.1.0).

#### Diagram:

> [Raspberry: 192.168.64.1] -> [Laptop: 192.168.64.2 - 192.168.1.1] -> [PC: 192.168.1.2]

Is there a way to do this at the OS level? Using routing tables/IP tables or so? SSH port forwarding? Any other way?

I don't want a workaround (I know I can use the Wi-Fi for example). But I want to learn a bit more about networking and different possibilities.

#### Edit to simplify it a bit:

I have three computers: A, B, and C.

A and B share Network X (192.168.1.0).
B and C share Network Y (192.168.64.0).

I want to connect A to C using SSH.

[A: 192.168.1.1] -> [B: 192.168.1.2 - 193.168.64.2] -> [C: 193.168.64.1]

#### Edit 2:

Workstation Tables:
[image: Workstation]

Laptop Tables:
[image: Laptop]

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are wanting to not SSH through your router, but SSH through the laptop which is connected to both networks. Do I have it now?

Comment: You write  in your title "attached to USB via SSH from another PC " <-- that is gibberish

Comment: I'm no expert but it sounds like your laptop may also be a router/gateway/have a routing table.. for your raspberry pi? So you perhaps need to somehow set up the PC's routing table so that anything to the IP network of your raspberry pi is sent to the laptop gateway/router?

Comment: Adding on to what @barlop said, this is also not my forte, but this other question may be helpful in changing your routing: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16057)

Comment: @barlop Someone edited my question. Re-editing it again. To your second comment, that is what I want to know how to do it, but internet is confusing (or I'm not understanding correctly).

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez look up what command from the cmd prompt shows the routing table from both computers the laptop and the PC.  The laptop , to get a btter understanding of what is going on. And the PC too 'cos that one you will probably add a line..  Include the output of both routing tables in your question

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez you could also go the SSH route but it is more limiting as you won't be able to ping the pi from the PC.  https://pastebin.com/raw/Wj7ct5gL (could vary that slightly to SSH from PC to pi). That's the with SSH solution, but see comment I made re routing table, include that in your question and so we can look into the without SSH solution as the without SSH solution includes ability to ping too

Comment: @barlop Tables added!

Comment: So your PI's IP is  192.168.64.1.  Can you also be clear A) IP Of workstation B) IP of laptop   Is it that your laptop and your PI are on network Y(192.168.64.0) . And you have two workstations on Network X (192.168.1.0)?

Comment: @barlop The Workstation have one IP: 192.168.1.10. My Laptop have two IPs as is in both Networks: 192.168.1.155 and 192.168.64.25. The Pi is 192.168.64.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118027/discussion-between-barlop-and-oscar-vicente-perez).

Comment: @barlop I can join the chat.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks to @barlop for all the help and guidance*

#### 1. Setting up static IPs:

First of all, I have to change the IPs of both the Raspberry and the Laptop second Network Adapter (The one in the same network of the Raspberry) to static IPs in the principal network range.

For example, my router creates 192.168.1.0 network, so I used two unassigned IPs in that range:

- In the Raspberry's /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, I changed the ptusb lines to:

```
interface ptusb
static ip_address=192.168.1.230/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 # Just example dns
```

- In the Laptop USB Network Adapter (Don't confuse with WiFi or Ethernet), I have this:

IP: 192.168.1.231
Mask: 255.255.255.0
All other fields in blank.

*Then I checked connectivity to the PI using the new IPs.*

#### 2. Bridge connections:

***Source:** https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10*

In order to allow the Raspberry to communicate with my home network, I had to bridge both my internet network (I was using WiFi) and the USB Network.

Steps:

1. First of all, use `ipconfig --all` and write down your current internet network configuration.
2. Select WiFi (or your internet network) and then the USB Network.
3. Right click, create bridge. Then wait.
4. A new Network will appear. Setup the IP and configuration you wrote down. Example:

[image: Bridge network]

5. DON'T FORGET TO **RESTART BOTH DEVICES**. It seems to work, but I didn't get internet after restarting the Laptop and connected to the WiFi.